# The requested resource is not available while publishing on tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat7

I'm trying to publish a simple java web service using tomcat. Referring to below screenshot, I have **HelloWorld.java** which is service interface and its **HelloWorldImpl.java** implementation class.

Also I've created **web.xml** and **sun-jaxws.xml**.

When I right click the project, select *Run As* and then *Run on Server*, I get 404 error message as shown in bottom of screenshot.

The URL which internal browser tries to reach is `http://localhost:8081/MySqlConnect/` where `MySqlConnect` is project name. Note that I'm using `8081` as port number.

I also tried `http://localhost:8081/HelloWorld/hello`, but it didn't worked.

I have also provided the code for all files below.

I'm not able to understand where am I going wrong? Any help appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

---

**HelloWorldImpl.java**

```
package com.mycompany.service;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mycompany.service.HelloWorld", serviceName = "HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    @Override
    public String sayGreeting(String name) {

        return "Greeting " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

---

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, 
Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

---

**sun-jaxws.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
    version="2.0">
    <endpoint name="HelloWorld" implementation="com.mycompany.service.HelloWorldImpl"
        url-pattern="/hello" />
</endpoints>
```

---

### Edit 1

**Log-cat**

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.33
 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/AddressingFeature$Responses
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/AddressingFeature$Responses
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature$Responses
```

---

### Edit 2

As suggested [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-xml-ws-soap-addressingfeatureresponses/), I downloaded all libraries and place in tomcat lib folder but now I get this error in log:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V not found
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V not found
```

If I add all libraries to project and then try to run it, I get following error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.spi.PolicyFeatureConfigurator: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.transport.tcp.policy.TCPTransportFeatureConfigurator is specified in jar:file:/C:/Apache-Tomcat-7/lib/webservices-rt-2.1-b16.jar!/META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.spi.PolicyFeatureConfiguratorbut could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException
com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.spi.PolicyFeatureConfigurator: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.transport.tcp.policy.TCPTransportFeatureConfigurator is specified in jar:file:/C:/Apache-Tomcat-7/lib/webservices-rt-2.1-b16.jar!/META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.spi.PolicyFeatureConfiguratorbut could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Note this: **com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.spi.PolicyFeatureConfiguratorbut could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException**

Comment: Are you sure it was deployed? Can you add server log?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution to yours? Did the marked answer work in your case? I also read the comments and put the jars under project's libs but still getting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V not found" error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct url is **`http://localhost:8081/MySqlConnect/hello`** as **MySqlConnect** is the name of your context and **hello** the web service url.

Also its a webservice so to access it properly you can make a SOAP call.

But the root cause is your web application is not starting due to unable to find class `javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature$Responses`.

Have you added right dependencies? Search in those dependencies if this class exists. `Response` is a **inner** class of `AddressingFeature`.

Comment: I have already tried `http://localhost:8081/MySqlConnect/hello`. But to no avail.

Comment: You forgot to read second part of my answer. Your webapp has not started so the url will not work. First you have to fix the error.

Comment: Requires jars should be copied to (1)only tomcat lib directory or (2)only web-inf directory of project or (3)both?

Comment: you should put them under WEB-INF/lib only

Comment: If I do that, I get `SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.spi.PolicyFeatureConfigurator: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.transport.tcp.policy.TCPTransportFeatureConfigurator is specified in jar:file:/C:/Apache-Tomcat-7/lib/webservices-rt-2.1-b16.jar!/META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.spi.PolicyFeatureConfiguratorbut could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException` :(

Comment: I also have the same problem. I put all the jars under project's libs but now getting: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V not found" error. Do you have any opinion about this problem?